# Geany fails to load the files in my base directory

Tags: geany

I just moved from Mac OS X Leopard to Ubuntu 12.04. I downloaded Geany and I want to continue coding there. However, when I create a new project, Geany does not import my files, it only shows the "untitled" file. The base directory is correct. I tried moving the files to another directory (changing the base directory), changing the permissions to 777, reinstalling Geany, downloading all the plugins, but to no avail. Anyone knows what might be happening? It is probably a noob mistake, but I cant find it!

Comment: your question is unclear to me.  Which files do you want Geany to import?  Congrats on using linux :)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the correct project base directory (as it sounds like you did), Geany will default to that directory when opening files. Unlike more complicated/advanced IDEs, Geany's project support is quite simple, it just points to a directory where you open files from and saves which files you had open at last shutdown/close. There is no "import" feature, if you have supported source files in the project base directory, Geany will allow you to edit them without doing anything special.

For some more info on Geany projects, [check out the manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#project-management). You might also like to check out some of the more advanced project plugins like [GProject](http://plugins.geany.org/gproject.html) if you want something more advanced than Geany's built-in simple projects.